# Different DropDownLists created at runtime do not allow selecting different items?

Tags: drop-down-menu, copy, runtime, items

I need to create many dropdownlists at runtime and select a different item for each one.
To avoid accessing the DB continuously I create a single dropdownlist of which I copy the items in the cloned dropdownlists. Strangely all the dropdownlists created select the item of the last dropdownlist and I don't understand why! I had to insert the cleaning of the selected items ["DlistClone.ClearSelection ()"] because otherwise the code goes wrong. Can anyone help me? thanks

```
   Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MyRow As New TableRow
    Dim MyCell As New TableCell

    Dim DList As DropDownList
    Dim DlistClone As DropDownList
    DList = New DropDownList
    DList.Items.Add("1")
    DList.Items.Add("2")
    DList.Items.Add("3")

    MyRow = New TableRow
    MyCell = New TableCell
    DlistClone = New DropDownList
    ClonaDList(DList, DlistClone)
    DlistClone.ClearSelection()
    DlistClone.Items.FindByText("3").Selected = True
    MyCell.Controls.Add(DlistClone)
    MyRow.Cells.Add(MyCell)

    Table1.Rows.Add(MyRow)

    MyRow = New TableRow
    MyCell = New TableCell
    DlistClone = New DropDownList
    ClonaDList(DList, DlistClone)
    DlistClone.ClearSelection()
    DlistClone.Items.FindByText("2").Selected = True
    MyCell.Controls.Add(DlistClone)
    MyRow.Cells.Add(MyCell)

    Table1.Rows.Add(MyRow)
End Sub

Sub ClonaDList(ByVal Origine As DropDownList, ByVal Destinazione As DropDownList)
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim EleList As ListItem

    For I = 0 To Origine.Items.Count - 1
        EleList = Origine.Items(I)
        Destinazione.Items.Add(EleList)
    Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it myself!
When I do

> EleList = Origin.Items (I)
>   Destination.Items.Add (EleList)

I create an inadvertent binding between the source Dropdownlist and the destination one.
To interrupt the binding I must necessarily use a bridge between the two controls, in this case I use the Listitem object by setting the 2 properties in 2 successive steps

```
Sub ClonaDList(ByRef Origine As DropDownList, ByRef Destinazione As DropDownList)
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim EleList As ListItem

    For I = 0 To Origine.Items.Count - 1
        EleList = New ListItem
        EleList.Text = Origine.Items(I).Text
        EleList.Value = Origine.Items(I).Value
        Destinazione.Items.Add(EleList)
    Next I
End Sub
```

Did I say it right?